# Multiple javascript colour pickers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a colour picker on my website. Which works great, However i'm wanting to have multiple for multiple elements to be different colour e.g. one text pink and the bg blue.

This is the code i have have at the moment (which works but changes both boxes) i'm missing an id somewhere but im not sure where.

```
  <div class="row">


  <script type="text/javascript">
  var hexText="123";
  var colorList = [ '000000', '993300', '333300', '003300', '003366', '000066', '333399', '333333',
  '660000', 'FF6633', '666633', '336633', '336666', '0066FF', '666699', '666666', 'CC3333', 'FF9933',
  '99CC33', '669966', '66CCCC', '3366FF', '663366', '999999', 'CC66FF', 'FFCC33', 'FFFF66', '99FF66'];

var picker = $('#color-picker');

for (var i = 0; i < colorList.length; i++ ) {
picker.append('<li class="color-item" data-hex="' + '#' + colorList[i] + '" style="background-color:' + '#' + colorList[i] + ';"></li>');
}

$('body').click(function () {
picker.fadeOut(1);
});

$('.call-picker').click(function(event) {
event.stopPropagation();
picker.fadeIn(1);
picker.children('li').hover(function() {
  var codeHex = $(this).data('hex');

  $('.color-holder').css('background-color', codeHex);
  $('#pickcolor').val(codeHex).trigger('change');
});
});
  </script>
      <div class="color-wrapper">
  <p>Choose color for Header</p>
   <!-- ng-model="eventData.header" This is to post the information in the color picker box into the json at the bottom to make it useable by the server. -->
  <form name="test">
  <input type="text" name="custom_color" ng-model="Data.headerColor" placeholder="#FFFFFF" id="pickcolor" class="call-picker">
</form>
  <div class="color-holder call-picker"></div>
  <div class="color-picker" id="color-picker" style="display: none"></div>
</div>




  </div>
  <div class="row">


  <script type="text/javascript">
  var hexText="123";
  var colorList = [ '000000', '993300', '333300', '003300', '003366', '000066', '333399', '333333',
  '660000', 'FF6633', '666633', '336633', '336666', '0066FF', '666699', '666666', 'CC3333', 'FF9933',
  '99CC33', '669966', '66CCCC', '3366FF', '663366', '999999', 'CC66FF', 'FFCC33', 'FFFF66', '99FF66'];

var picker = $('#color-picker2');

for (var i = 0; i < colorList.length; i++ ) {
picker.append('<li class="color-item" data-hex="' + '#' + colorList[i] + '" style="background-color:' + '#' + colorList[i] + ';"></li>');
}

$('body').click(function () {
picker.fadeOut(1);
});

$('.call-picker2').click(function(event) {
event.stopPropagation();
picker.fadeIn(1);
picker.children('li').hover(function() {
  var codeHex = $(this).data('hex');

  $('.color-holder2').css('background-color', codeHex);
  $('#pickcolor2').val(codeHex).trigger('change');
});
});
  </script>
      <div class="color-wrapper">
  <p>Choose color for Header</p>
   <!-- ng-model="eventData.header" This is to post the information in the color picker box into the json at the bottom to make it useable by the server. -->
  <form name="test">
  <input type="text" name="custom_color2" ng-model="Data.bodytextColor" placeholder="#FFFFFF" id="pickcolor2" class="call-picker2">
</form>
  <div class="color-holder2 call-picker2"></div>
  <div class="color-picker2" id="color-picker2" style="display: none"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or codepen for that code? Difficult to know what you're asking at this point.

Comment: You might want to consider splitting your javascript and HTML, this looks pretty messy and isn't easy to read.

Comment: The number 1 rule for being able to extend your code in this kind of way is to avoid using global variables. Because `picker` is global (and other vars), you would have to replicate everything to make it work. Move all the code related to `picker` into a self-contain function where you pass the variables in and it doesn't use any globals. Then you should just be able to call it twice with a different field ID.

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't mind not supporting IE, you could just use HTML5 `<input type=colour>` and have the browser do all the colour picker work for you. You might not actually need any of that code at all.

Comment: If it work for you, can you select an accepted answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`picker` variable must change.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var hexText="123";
  var colorList = [ '000000', '993300', '333300', '003300', '003366', '000066', '333399', '333333',
  '660000', 'FF6633', '666633', '336633', '336666', '0066FF', '666699', '666666', 'CC3333', 'FF9933',
  '99CC33', '669966', '66CCCC', '3366FF', '663366', '999999', 'CC66FF', 'FFCC33', 'FFFF66', '99FF66'];

var picker2 = $('#color-picker2');

for (var i = 0; i < colorList.length; i++ ) {
picker2.append('<li class="color-item" data-hex="' + '#' + colorList[i] + '" style="background-color:' + '#' + colorList[i] + ';"></li>');
}

$('body').click(function () {
picker2.fadeOut(1);
});

$('.call-picker2').click(function(event) {
event.stopPropagation();
picker2.fadeIn(1);
picker2.children('li').hover(function() {
  var codeHex = $(this).data('hex');

  $('.color-holder2').css('background-color', codeHex);
  $('#pickcolor2').val(codeHex).trigger('change');
});
});
  </script>
```